# How to Identify Delay signed assembly

Tags: .net, .net-assembly

I have lot of assemblies inside one folder. Only some of them are marked for delay signing.

Now, I have to sign all those assemblies who have marked for delay signing.

How to identity which assembly is marked for delay signing and which is not?

Answer (score 7):

You need to use sn -vf

Verify  for strong name signature self consistency. If -vf is
specified, force verification even if disabled in the registry.

Answer (score 6):

You can run `sn -v "path to your assembly"`. This will output `xxx is a delay-signed or test-signed assembly` if the assembly is delay signed.

If you prefer to do it in .NET, you may want to use `StrongNameSignatureVerificationEx` to check the signature (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnfa/archive/2004/06/07/150378.aspx)

```
[DllImport("mscoree.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
static extern bool StrongNameSignatureVerificationEx(string wszFilePath, bool fForceVerification, ref bool pfWasVerified);
```

Comment: `sn -v` doesn't show me `xxx is a delay-signed or test-signed assembly`. `sn -vf` does.